# android studio and sqlite count duplicate values

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I don't know how to count repeated party value. please help me anyone, it is very useful for my college project. i stored my data in sqlite database, here i attached my table screenshot. i need to show how many DMK, ADMK and BJP. like  DMK = 5, ADMK = 3, BJP = 3. to show on toast. 
[image: Table]

if anyone tell me how to modify my coding and give me some relevant coding.

***Votingpage.java***

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_votingpage);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        emailview = findViewById(R.id.emailview);
        edtaadhar1 = findViewById(R.id.edtaadhar1);
        btnlogout = findViewById(R.id.btnlogout);
        btnadd = findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
        btncheck = findViewById(R.id.btncheck);
        radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

        dmk = findViewById(R.id.dmk);


        AddData();


        FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        emailview.setText(firebaseUser.getEmail());

        btncheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        btnlogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Votingpage.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

        private void AddData() {
            btnadd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (edtaadhar1.getText().toString().trim().length() <= 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(Votingpage.this, "Please enter aadhar no", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {


                    int radioid = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                    radioButton = findViewById(radioid);

                    boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(radioButton.getText().toString(),edtaadhar1.getText().toString());
                    if (isInserted = true)
                        Toast.makeText(Votingpage.this, "Thanks for giving your vote", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    else
                        Toast.makeText(Votingpage.this, "data not inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void check_button(View v){
        int radioid = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

        radioButton = findViewById(radioid);
    }
}
```

***DatabaseHelper.java***

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Vote.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "voter_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "PARTY";
    public static final String COL_3 = "AADHAR";



    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,PARTY TEXT,AADHAR INTEGER)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public boolean insertData(String party,String aadhar) {
        if (!isValueExist(aadhar)) {


            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(COL_2, party);
            contentValues.put(COL_3, aadhar);


            long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
            return result != -1;
        }else {
                return false;

        }

    }

    private boolean isValueExist(String aadhar) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_3 + " = ?";
        String[] whereArgs = {aadhar};

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, whereArgs);

        int count = cursor.getCount();

        cursor.close();

        return count >= 1;
    }


    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
        return res;
    }




}
```

Comment: Use group by and count statements:: `SELECT party, COUNT(id) FROM voter_table GROUP BY party`. See https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group-by/

Answer (score 1):

You need a method for this query:

```
select PARTY, count(PARTY) from voter_table group by PARTY;
```

It will return 2 columns i.e. PARTY name and count.

**EDIT:**

Use this method to get Data:

```
public List<Data> getPartyCountData() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select PARTY, count(PARTY) from voter_table group by PARTY", null);
    List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String partyName = cursor.getString(0);
        Integer partyCount = cursor.getInt(1);
        Data data = new Data(partyName, partyCount);
        dataList.add(data);
    }
    return dataList;
}
```

And Create a POJO Data.java

```
public class Data {
    String partyName;
    Integer partyCount;

    public Data(String partyName, Integer partyCount) {
        this.partyName = partyName;
        this.partyCount = partyCount;
    }

    public String getPartyName() {
        return partyName;
    }

    public void setPartyName(String partyName) {
        this.partyName = partyName;
    }

    public Integer getPartyCount() {
        return partyCount;
    }

    public void setPartyCount(Integer partyCount) {
        this.partyCount = partyCount;
    }
}
```

You will get All Party Name and Count in List of Data.

Comment: thank you for your answer, where i implement to this method and how to modify the code, i'm fresher, please help me and give me some example to relevant my coding.

Comment: dear sir, i need your help please give a solution. i don't known how to implement this method, give me some example to relevant my coding.

Comment: thank you for your reply, how to show this method in toast msg.